# EXCEL: Cell.Value returning preceding "?"

Tags: excel, cell

I'm returning a cell value in part of my code, and then cleaning the data to remove illegal filename characters.  One of these characters is of course the "?" and for some reason, some of my cells are returning the contents with a preceding ? despite this not being part of the cell.

Furthermore, the code I'm using to clean the string is not replacing this leading ? with a whitespace as I'd hoped it did.

```
Function Clean(ByVal sFolderName As String) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim sTemp As String

For i = 1 To Len(sFolderName)
      Select Case Mid$(sFolderName, i, 1)
         Case "/", "", ":", "*", "?", "<", ">", "|"
             sTemp = sTemp & ""
         Case Else
             sTemp = sTemp & Mid$(sFolderName, i, 1)
     End Select
 Next i

Clean = sTemp

End Function
```

For example, the value in a cell would show as 8324297444, but when trying to retrieve the cell.value property it returns ?8324297444.  Then, when the clean-up function is called, it will keep this leading ? character.

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out what's going on here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any reason to use a custom function? You could use the Excel RE.Replace function that uses regex.

Comment: Never heard of this, when I try to use it in excel, it doesn't apprear to be a function.  Do I need to include some kind of library?

Comment: Google it! https://www.google.ca/search?ix=hca&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=excel+regex+replace

Comment: Excel will use "?" when it does not have a symbol for a character.  If the problem cell is A1 try `=CODE(A1)` in another cell.  This will display the code number for the first character of A1 even if it is invisible.  Alternatively, `=CODE(MID(A1,2,1)` will allow you to check the second character of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting this for days, it appears to be an isolated incident which cannot be corrected.  I have exhaused all possible suggestions provided on SO and other sources around the net.

I was able to rectify the situation by identifying the data that was affected by this behaviour and re-keying it manually.

It was not the most efficient solution, but it did solve the problem.

If you encounter this problem, please be advised that this is the only fix I was able to find.

Answer (score 1):

And by the way, question marks(?) and asterix (*) are Excel special caracters. Try using a tild caracter to escape the special caracters like so:

```
       Case "/", "", ":", "~*", "~?", "<", ">", "|"
```

EDIT: then try with the caracter code like this:

```
       Case "/", "", ":", CHR(42), CHR(63), "<", ">", "|"
```

Comment: ASCII codes didn't work either.  As far as I can tell, Excel is appending this leading "?" to the data right before the Clean() function is called.